# C# Validate xml against multiple schemas xsd

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd, schema

I am looking for a way to validate my xml file against multiple xsd schemas in memory or at runtime without touching the disk filesystem.

Let's say I have an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<addresses xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='test.xsd'>
</addresses>
```

then there is a schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<schema targetNamespace="xxx">
   <!-- include and import declarations -->
   <include schemaLocation="another.xsd"/>
   <import schemaLocation="dev.xsd"/>
 <!--
   this .xsd does not have any schema components defined.
   removed from schema file set.    
   <include schemaLocation="new.xsd"/>
  -->
 <include schemaLocation="old.xsd"/>
 <include schemaLocation="test4.xsd"/>
 <include schemaLocation="test2.xsd"/>
 <include schemaLocation="test3.xsd"/>
```

Let's say that some dumbed down diagram looks like this:

```
                                  test.xsd
                          |            |         |
                        test1.xsd  test2.xsd  test3.xsd
                          |     |         
                   test5.xsd   test6.xsd
```

and so on...

When I am using any tool for schema validation purpose and I will put all those xsd files in one folder then I can validate the xml just fine.

I would like to achieve the same effect without using a directory on a filesystem.
I was thinking about puting all those xsd in a zip then at runtime get them back and put them in XmlSchemaSet. The problem is that I may have some additional xsd files that are not related to the test.xml.

Is there any way to validate the xml with mutiple xsd in memory? I was thinking about using:

```
           foreach (String singleSchema in schema.listOfSchemasReferenced)
            {
                using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(singleSchema))
                using (XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader))
                {
                    var includeSchema = XmlSchema.Read(xmlReader, null);

                    var include = new XmlSchemaInclude();
                    include.Schema = includeSchema;
                    if (mainSchema.TargetNamespace != includeSchema.TargetNamespace)
                        continue;
                    mainSchema.Includes.Add(include);
                }
            }
```

I am getting errors then  I am trying compile schemaset because the listOfSchemasReferenced may have a lot of unrealated xsd placed in the same folder.
While i was looking through the web, i've seen that XmlResolver may be usefull but I am not sure how to use in the context of validation multiple xsd in a context of files placed in a .zip and memory.
If you have any ideas how to solve this problem or you have some examples that I could read that would be great. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ended up writing a custom xml resolver using a approach like bellow:

```
    class XmlResolver : XmlUrlResolver
    {
        internal const string BaseUri = "schema://";

        public override object GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, string role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
        {
            if (absoluteUri.Scheme == "schema")
            {
                switch (absoluteUri.LocalPath)
                {
                    case "/ADDRESS.xsd":
                        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Resource.ADDRESS));
                    case "/PERSON.xsd":
                        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Resource.PERSON));
                }
            }
            return base.GetEntity(absoluteUri, role, ofObjectToReturn);
        }
    }
```